# The Spring Cloud Dataflow UI is not refreshing the status correctly

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

The deploy status shows undeployed in latest Spring Cloud Dataflow UI though it's deployed

[image]

[image]

Name: spring-cloud-dataflow-server
Version: 2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Checked the kubernetes, the pod creation seems to get stuck though stream status is deploy and undeploy. Only on deleting the resource section in deploy yaml pods for both app get created. I have encountered this delete resource section to create app pod few times.

Comment: Hi, @techpro. If this reproducible, please open an issue in GH with as many details as possible. We can have a look.

Comment: Thank you filed it in GH

Comment: Is there any way to change the default resource limit in SCDF (environment/config etc..) to over come this issue as on deploy always the resource get set to below and fails. resources:
limits:
cpu: 500m
memory: 1Gi

Comment: @SabbyAnandan Below was the root cause for this issue. Increasing the kubernetes node(machine) CPU size fixed the problem. Able to deploy without any issues. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33777

Comment: Ah, yeah, this is a common problem. As soon as you describe the pods that aren't able to start, you would have spotted this right away. Anyway, I am glad you were able to get things up and running. We will still check the UI/API calls on our side.